# Users adding Images to a Slideshow through Posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Since Stackexchange's WordPress-forum is nearly unpopulated, I thought I'd ask the same question here, since this is where I usually post.

**Original post:** https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70742/users-adding-images-to-a-slideshow-through-posts

I'm puzzling with a page, where I want users to be able to create their own posts—for this I use the plug-in [WP User Frontend](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/).

Each post consists of various text-fields including description, location, contact information and finally a featured image (thumbnail).

Now, I want to add the feature that could enable my users to add up-to five self-picked pictures to a slideshow—each post a user make should contain a slideshow. How would I do that?

If I could make WP User Frontend work together with an already existing slideshow plug-in (e.g. [Meteor Slides](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meteor-slides/) or [Slideshow](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slideshow-jquery-image-gallery/)?) I would reckon it could work? Maybe through a custom PHP-statement?

I've tried doing this for days. Now I'm turning to you in the hopes of finally solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

in order to upload pictures externally paste these codes in your functions.php

```
function uploadImage($new_post){
 $inc = 1;    
 if ($_FILES) {
   foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {          
      $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$new_post);
      // $newupload returns the attachment id of the file that
      // was just uploaded. Do whatever you want with that now.
      $inc++;
   }
 }

}

function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id) {

 // check to make sure its a successful upload
 if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) return false;

require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );  
}
```

and call the uploadimage function in your template with your new post id

```
uploadImage($the_post_id);
```

just put five upload input form and itll automatically read by the functions

Comment: I didn't receive a notification from your post - that's why I reply so late. I want to post the `uploadImage($the_post_id);` inside of the standard `single.php`-template, which means, I'd like the `$the_post_id` to be selected automatically - do you know how?

Comment: if you want to get the single.php current post id then you can do it like this: global $post; uploadImage($post->ID);

Comment: `<?php global $post; uploadImage($post->ID); ?>` didn't display all the uploaded images from the post. The images are still displayed from the `<?php the_content(); ?>`. I'm by the way using the plug-in `Post from Site` now, since `WP User Frontend` couldn't attach more than 1 image to it's frontend form.

Comment: Can't you help me figure this out, @loQ?